# How to hide ModelEntity in RealityKit?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

There are hide model in Reality Composer but can't find any docs about hide entity or `ModelEntity` in RealityKit.

Something like this :

```
SCNNode ---- hidden
```

A Boolean value that determines the visibility of the node’s contents. Animatable.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at isEnabled, I believe it does the same as SCNNode.hidden

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/entity/3244077-isenabled